# How to fix a non responding ext.list?

Tags: sencha-touch, removeall, ext.list

I've got  a problem with an Ext.List:

You press a button on the main menu and are shown the list. Everything on it works fine and it let's you choose, where to go deeper inside the app. No problems so far.
But if you then go back to the main menu by pressing a "back"-button and reenter the page, that shows this Ext.List, it doesn't work anymore: you can't select an entry of the list.

The "back"-button removes the list, if you return to the main menu this way:

`setTimeout(function(){page.removeAll();},100);`

What's my mistake? Do you know a better method than "page.removeAll()" that really kills this Ext.List to let it then be completely recreated when I choose to see it in my main menu?

Thanks in advance, you guys have the best tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code but I suspect that there is a javascript error somewhere in the program flow that you described. If you display the javascript console in either Chrome or Firefox it should show the error.

Depending upon how the function that creates the list is defined it would normally recreate the list upon page/function entry and there should be no need to 'kill' the list explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That's what I thought it would do: recreate it. But it doesn't do that as far as I can tell. Furthermore the Safari Developer Console shows no error. Which part of the code do you need?